# Deserialization of json with serde by a numerical value as type identifier

Tags: rust, enums, json-deserialization, serde

I'm quite new to rust and come from an OOP background. So, maybe I misunderstood some rust basics.

I want to parse a fixed json-structure with serde. This structure represents one of different messages types. Each message has a numeric `type` attribute to distinguish it. The exact structure of the individual message types varies mostly, but they can also be the same.

```
{"type": 1, "sender_id": 4, "name": "sender", ...}
{"type": 2, "sender_id": 5, "measurement": 3.1415, ...}
{"type": 3, "sender_id": 6, "measurement": 13.37, ...}
...
```

First of all, I defined an `enum` to distinguish between message types also a `struct` for each type of message without a field storing the type.

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Message {
    T1(Type1),
    T2(Type2),
    T3(Type3),
    // ...
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Type1 {
    sender_id: u32,
    name: String,
    // ...
}
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Type2 {
    sender_id: u32,
    measurement: f64,
    // ...
}
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Type3 {
    sender_id: u32,
    measurement: f64,
    // ...
}
// ...
```

When I try to turn a string to a `Message` object, I get an error.

```
let message = r#"{"type":1,"sender_id":123456789,"name":"sender"}"#;
let message: Message = serde_json::from_str(message)?; // error here
// Error: Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: Error("invalid type: integer `1`, expected variant identifier", line: 1, column: 9) }
```

So, as I understood, serde tries to figure out the type of the current message but it needs a string
for that. I also tried to write my own `deserialize()`-function. I tried to get the numerical value
of the corresponding `type`-key and wanted to create the specific object by the type value.

How I have to implement the `deserialize()` to extract the type of the message and create the specific message object? Is it possible to write this without writing a `deserialize()`-function for each `Type1/2/3/...` struct?

```
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Message {
fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
                  where D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    // which functions I have to call?
}
```

Or is there a better solution to achieve my deserialization?

I prepared a playground for this issue: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d328fc6d9c777b4fddc71f1a93dee473)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Serde doesn't support integer tags yet (see [issue #745](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/745)).

---

If you're able to change what's producing the data, then if you're able to change `type` into a string, i.e. `"1"` instead of `1`. Then you can get it working simply using [`#[serde(rename)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#rename).

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Message {
    #[serde(rename = "1")]
    T1(Type1),
    #[serde(rename = "2")]
    T2(Type2),
    #[serde(rename = "3")]
    T3(Type3),
    // ...
}
```

---

If that's not an option, then you indeed need to create a custom deserializer. The shortest in terms of code, is likely to deserialize into a [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/enum.Value.html), and then match on the `type`, and *deserialize* the `serde_json::Value` into the correct `Type{1,2,3}`.

```rust
use serde_json::Value;

impl<'de> serde::Deserialize<'de> for Message {
    fn deserialize<D: serde::Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        let value = Value::deserialize(d)?;

        Ok(match value.get("type").and_then(Value::as_u64).unwrap() {
            1 => Message::T1(Type1::deserialize(value).unwrap()),
            2 => Message::T2(Type2::deserialize(value).unwrap()),
            3 => Message::T3(Type3::deserialize(value).unwrap()),
            type_ => panic!("unsupported type {:?}", type_),
        })
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to perform some proper [error handling](https://serde.rs/error-handling.html), instead of unwrapping and panicking.

---

If you need serialization as well, then you will likewise need a custom serializer. For this you could create a new type to serialize into, as you cannot use `Message`.

```rust
use serde::Serializer;

impl Serialize for Message {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        #[derive(Serialize)]
        #[serde(untagged)]
        enum Message_<'a> {
            T1(&'a Type1),
            T2(&'a Type2),
            T3(&'a Type3),
        }

        #[derive(Serialize)]
        struct TypedMessage<'a> {
            #[serde(rename = "type")]
            t: u64,
            #[serde(flatten)]
            msg: Message_<'a>,
        }

        let msg = match self {
            Message::T1(t) => TypedMessage { t: 1, msg: Message_::T1(t) },
            Message::T2(t) => TypedMessage { t: 2, msg: Message_::T2(t) },
            Message::T3(t) => TypedMessage { t: 3, msg: Message_::T3(t) },
        };
        msg.serialize(serializer)
    }
}
```

---

When using [`#[serde(flatten)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#flatten), then it uses [`serde::private::ser::FlatMapSerializer`](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/8847800ce2cf404ae5f02485f030e380b246421e/serde/src/private/ser.rs#L1028), which is hidden from the documentation. In place of creating new types, you could use [`SerializeMap`](https://docs.rs/serde/*/serde/ser/trait.SerializeMap.html) and `FlatMapSerializer`.

However, be warned, given it's undocumented, then any future release of serde *could* break your code if you're using `FlatMapSerializer` directly.

```rust
use serde::{private::ser::FlatMapSerializer, ser::SerializeMap, Serializer};

impl Serialize for Message {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut s = serializer.serialize_map(None)?;

        let type_ = &match self {
            Message::T1(_) => 1,
            Message::T2(_) => 2,
            Message::T3(_) => 3,
        };
        s.serialize_entry("type", &type_)?;

        match self {
            Message::T1(t) => t.serialize(FlatMapSerializer(&mut s))?,
            Message::T2(t) => t.serialize(FlatMapSerializer(&mut s))?,
            Message::T3(t) => t.serialize(FlatMapSerializer(&mut s))?,
        }

        s.end()
    }
}
```

Comment: The second solution is what I was searching for. Works well. Serialization is needed indeed. Thank you.