# serde: deserialize a field based on the value of another field

Tags: rust, serde

I would like to deserialize a wire format, like this JSON, into the `Data` structure below and I am failing to write the serde `Deserialize` implementations for the corresponding rust types.

```json
{ "type": "TypeA", "value": { "id": "blah", "content": "0xa1b.." } }
```

```rust
enum Content {
   TypeA(Vec<u8>),
   TypeB(BigInt), 
}

struct Value {
    id: String,
    content: Content,
}

struct Data {
   typ: String,
   value: Value,
}
```

The difficulty is selecting the correct value of the `Content` enumeration, which is based on the `typ` value.
As far as I know, deserialization in serde is stateless, an hence there is no way of either

- knowing what the value of `typ` is at the time of deserialization of `content` (even though the deserialization order is guaranteed)
- or injecting the value of `typ` in the deserializer then collecting it.

How can this be achieved with serde ?

I have looked at

- [serde_state](https://docs.rs/serde_state/0.4.8/serde_state/index.html) but I cannot get the macros working and this library is wrapping serde, which worries me
- [DeserializeSeed](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeSeed.html) but my undestanding is that it must be used in place of `Deserialize` for *all* types and my data model is big

The existing SO answers usually exploit the fact that the related fields are at the same level. This is not the case here: the actual data model is big, deep and the fields are "far apart"

Comment: Is the data from an external source?

Comment: Are all variants of `Content` guaranteed to be the same? If not, is your actual format more complex? Because if not, then manually `impl Deserialize for Data` might be a straightforward solution

Comment: @Netwave yes, an external source. I cannot change the format (but can hold them in memory)

Comment: @vallentin I am not sure I understand what you mean by "same". In the actual model there are a dozen (fixed) variants. There 3 levels of nesting between `typ` and `content` in the real model

Comment: @BrunoGrieder, you can implement your custom deserialize. Should be difficult. Just deserialize into an intermediary Json::Value, extract what you need from there and build the items.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder I meant, if all variants of `Content` was e.g. "`Vec<u8>`", as then the a custom deserialize implementation could be simplified. If not, the straightforward way might be to deserialize into `serde_json::Value` as @Netwave suggested. It might also be possible to have another custom intermediary type, and use [`#[serde(try_from = "...")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from) to automatically convert from it

Comment: @vallentin ah ok. No they are not all the same. I amended the example

Comment: @vallentin. Not sure how this helps since I cannot inject "what I extracted and need" in serde `Deserialize`  or are you suggesting that I manually parse the `Json::Value` into the structs ? Also, the data is not necessarily coming from Json but a wire format also (and XML potentially)

Comment: https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#adjacently-tagged

Comment: @Stargateur, I dont think tagging would really work here, since the tag will not refer to `Data` but to `Content`.

Comment: @Netwave I pretty sure of myself, that not because OP choice a bad data format you need to follow it. The enum must be rewrite.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder please provide a better [mcve], you can't say "In the actual model" and expect we guess it. Provide code and input, with `assert_eq!` that show what you want. Don't omit detail you think is trivial.

Comment: @Stargateur, oh, yeah, ofc, it changing the structs that would work indeed.

Comment: @Stargateur The minimal example is what you have in the post. If you can make it work for it, I can make it work for the actual model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few different ways this can be solved, e.g. with a custom `impl Deserialize for Data`, then deserialize into a [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/*/serde_json/enum.Value.html), and then manually juggling between the types.

For a *somewhat* example of that, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575385/deserialization-of-json-with-serde-by-a-numerical-value-as-type-identifier/65576570#65576570) that I wrote in the past. It's not a one-to-one solution, but it might give some hints for implementing `Deserialize` manually, for what you want.

---

That being said. Personally, I prefer to minimize when I have to `impl Deserialize` manually, and instead deserialize into another type, and have it automatically convert using [`#[serde(from = "FromType")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from).

First, instead of `type_: String`, I'd suggest we introduce `enum ContentType`.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Clone, Copy, Debug)]
enum ContentType {
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC,
    TypeD,
}
```

Now, let's consider the types you introduced. I've added a few extra variants to `Content`, as you mentioned the variants can be different.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Content {
    TypeA(Vec<u8>),
    TypeB(Vec<u8>),
    TypeC(String),
    TypeD { foo: i32, bar: i32 },
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Value {
    id: String,
    content: Content,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(try_from = "IntermediateData")]
struct Data {
    #[serde(alias = "type")]
    type_: ContentType,
    value: Value,
}
```

Nothing crazy yet or much different. All the "magic" happens in the `IntermediateData` type, along with the `impl TryFrom`.

---

First, let's introduce a `check_type()`, which takes a `ContentType` and checks it against the `Content`. If the `Content` variant doesn't match the `ContentType` variant, then convert it.

In short, when using [`#[serde(untagged)]`](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) then when serde attempts to deserialize `Content` it will always return the first successful variant it can deserialize to if any. So if it can deserialize a `Vec<u8>`, then it will always result in `Content::TypeA()`. Knowing this, then in our `check_type()`, if the `ContentType` is `TypeB` and the `Content` is `TypeA`. Then we simply change it to `TypeB`.

```rust
impl Content {
    // TODO: impl proper error type instead of `String`
    fn check_type(self, type_: ContentType) -> Result<Self, String> {
        match (type_, self) {
            (ContentType::TypeA, content @ Self::TypeA(_)) => Ok(content),
            (ContentType::TypeB, Self::TypeA(content)) => Ok(Self::TypeB(content)),
            (ContentType::TypeC | ContentType::TypeD, content) => Ok(content),
            (type_, content) => Err(format!(
                "unexpected combination of {:?} and {:?}",
                type_, content
            )),
        }
    }
}
```

Now all we need is the intermediate `IntermediateData`, along with a `TryFrom` conversion, which calls `check_type()` on the `Content`.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct IntermediateData {
    #[serde(alias = "type")]
    type_: ContentType,
    value: Value,
}

impl TryFrom<IntermediateData> for Data {
    // TODO: impl proper error type instead of `String`
    type Error = String;

    fn try_from(mut data: IntermediateData) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        data.value.content = data.value.content.check_type(data.type_)?;

        Ok(Data {
            type_: data.type_,
            value: data.value,
        })
    }
}
```

That's all. Now we can test it against the following:

```rust
// serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
// serde_json = "1.0"

use std::convert::TryFrom;

use serde::Deserialize;

// ... all the previous code ...

fn main() {
    let json = r#"{ "type": "TypeA", "value": { "id": "foo", "content": [0, 1, 2, 3] } }"#;
    let data: Data = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", data);

    let json = r#"{ "type": "TypeB", "value": { "id": "foo", "content": [0, 1, 2, 3] } }"#;
    let data: Data = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", data);

    let json = r#"{ "type": "TypeC", "value": { "id": "bar", "content": "foo" } }"#;
    let data: Data = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", data);

    let json = r#"{ "type": "TypeD", "value": { "id": "baz", "content": { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 } } }"#;
    let data: Data = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", data);
}
```

Then it correctly results in `Data`s with `Content::TypeA`, `Content::TypeB`, `Content::TypeC`, and the last one `Content::TypeD`.

---

Lastly. There is [issue #939](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/939) which talks about adding a `#[serde(validate = "...")]`. However, it was created in 2017, so I wouldn't hold my breath on it.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer. Heavy handed but interesting self correcting approach where you deserialize to what you can then fix it. Will definitely give it a go. I think you can even simplify by letting serde deserialize to a an instance of `Data` then directly (post)fixing that instance

Comment: Definitely a possibility. One downside to that though, is that someone might forget to call "`data.fix()`". Though it could ofc all be hidden away with a function and calling `Data::from_json(...)`, instead of `serde_json::from_str::<Data>(...)` :)

Comment: After testing the various answers, I think this is the most sensible and efficient approach, even if not ideal: let serde do what it can do and postfix what needs to be.

Comment: How to read value.content.foo or value.content[0]?

Comment: @Ant use `match value.content` and match on the `Value` variant

Comment: Thanx @vallentin. The `#[serde(from = "FromType")]` suggestion was excellent. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

***Much simpler*** using [tagging](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#adjacently-tagged), but changing your data structure:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer}; // 1.0.130
use serde_json; // 1.0.67

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type", content = "value")]
enum Data {
   TypeA(Value<String>),
   TypeB(Value<u32>), 
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Value<T> {
    id: String,
    content: T,
}



fn main() {
    let input = r#"{"type": "TypeA", "value": { "id": "blah", "content": "0xa1b..."}}"#;
    let data: Data = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

[Playground](http://use%20serde::%7BDeserialize,%20Deserializer%7D;//%201.0.130%20use%20serde_json;%20//%201.0.67%20%20#%5Bderive(Debug,%20Deserialize)%5D%20#%5Bserde(tag%20=%20%22type%22,%20content%20=%20%22value%22)%5D%20enum%20Data%20%7B%20%20%20%20TypeA(Value%3CString%3E),%20%20%20%20TypeB(Value%3Cu32%3E),%20%20%7D%20%20#%5Bderive(Debug,%20Deserialize)%5D%20struct%20Value%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20id:%20String,%20%20%20%20%20content:%20T,%20%7D%20%20%20%20fn%20main()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20let%20input%20=%20r#%22%7B%22type%22:%20%22TypeA%22,%20%22value%22:%20%7B%20%22id%22:%20%22blah%22,%20%22content%22:%20%220xa1b...%22%7D%7D%22#;%20%20%20%20%20let%20data:%20Data%20=%20serde_json::from_str(&input).unwrap();%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B:?%7D%22,%20data);%20%7D)

Also, you can write your own custom desializer using some intermediary `serde_json::Value`:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};// 1.0.130
use serde_json; // 1.0.67

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Content {
   TypeA(String),
   TypeB(String), 
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Value {
    id: String,
    content: Content,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data {
   typ: String,
   value: Value,
}


impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Data {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let json: serde_json::value::Value = serde_json::value::Value::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        let typ = json.get("type").expect("type").as_str().unwrap();
        let value = json.get("value").expect("value");
        
        let id = value.get("id").expect("id").as_str().unwrap();
        let content = value.get("content").expect("content").as_str().unwrap();
        
        Ok(Data {
            typ: typ.to_string(),
            value: Value {
                id: id.to_string(),
                content: {
                    match typ {
                        "TypeA" => Content::TypeA(content.to_string()),
                        "TypeB" => Content::TypeB(content.to_string()),
                        _ => panic!("Invalid type, but this should be an error not a panic"),
                    }
                }
            }
        })    
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"{"type": "TypeA", "value": { "id": "blah", "content": "0xa1b..."}}"#;
    let data: Data = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7cebbfda8a8d6e501ef38da16bb4cdb)

Disclaimer: I didn't handle error correctly and you could also extract the content matching into a function for example. The above code is just to illustrate the main idea.

Comment: Now I feel silly for my solution, didn't think of flipping it around. Only downside is if you want variants with fields. Though it is way easier to have a separate struct for those, than using my solution, which requires some manual _type_ checking :)

Comment: Thanks. I am reviewing tagging and will revert. Wrt to using a value object (acting as a cache), I have a few problems, the main one is that the object that englobes the two related fields (`Data` here) must be entirely described to be instantiated in its `Deserialize` implementation - and my objects are big

Comment: Tagging seems to work fine with adjacent tags but is hard to get working otherwise and hence require model modifications. Not an option in my case

Answer (score 1):

`DeserializeSeed` can be mixed with normal `Deserialize` code. It does not need to be used for all types. Here, it is enough to use it to deserialize `Value`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f6c8a3d36fbe001322f5586192ab0ec)

```rust
use serde::de::{DeserializeSeed, IgnoredAny, MapAccess, Visitor};
use serde::*;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ContentType {
    A,
    B,
    Unknown,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Content {
    TypeA(String),
    TypeB(i32),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Value {
    id: String,
    content: Content,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data {
    typ: String,
    value: Value,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Data {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct DataVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for DataVisitor {
            type Value = Data;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("struct Data")
            }

            fn visit_map<A>(self, mut access: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: MapAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut typ = None;
                let mut value = None;

                while let Some(key) = access.next_key()? {
                    match key {
                        "type" => {
                            typ = Some(access.next_value()?);
                        }
                        "value" => {
                            let seed = match typ.as_deref() {
                                Some("TypeA") => ContentType::A,
                                Some("TypeB") => ContentType::B,
                                _ => ContentType::Unknown,
                            };
                            value = Some(access.next_value_seed(seed)?);
                        }
                        _ => {
                            access.next_value::<IgnoredAny>()?;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Ok(Data {
                    typ: typ.unwrap(),
                    value: value.unwrap(),
                })
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_map(DataVisitor)
    }
}

impl<'de> DeserializeSeed<'de> for ContentType {
    type Value = Value;

    fn deserialize<D>(self, deserializer: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct ValueVisitor(ContentType);

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for ValueVisitor {
            type Value = Value;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("struct Value")
            }

            fn visit_map<A>(self, mut access: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: MapAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut id = None;
                let mut content = None;

                while let Some(key) = access.next_key()? {
                    match key {
                        "id" => {
                            id = Some(access.next_value()?);
                        }
                        "content" => {
                            content = Some(match self.0 {
                                ContentType::A => Content::TypeA(access.next_value()?),
                                ContentType::B => Content::TypeB(access.next_value()?),
                                ContentType::Unknown => {
                                    panic!("Should not happen if type happens to occur before value, but JSON is unordered.");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        _ => {
                            access.next_value::<IgnoredAny>()?;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Ok(Value {
                    id: id.unwrap(),
                    content: content.unwrap(),
                })
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_map(ValueVisitor(self))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let j = r#"{"type": "TypeA", "value": {"id": "blah", "content": "0xa1b.."}}"#;
    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<Data>(j).unwrap());
    let j = r#"{"type": "TypeB", "value": {"id": "blah", "content": 666}}"#;
    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<Data>(j).unwrap());
    let j = r#"{"type": "TypeB", "value": {"id": "blah", "content": "Foobar"}}"#;
    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<Data>(j).unwrap_err());
}
```

The main downside of this solution is that you lose the possibility of deriving the code.

Comment: +1 Thanks for correcting this. This what I meant but incorrectly stated: you loose the ability to derive. Too bad `DeserializeSeed` does no extend `Deserialize`